# System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit and .MaxServicePointIdleTime

Tags: .net, asp.net, rest, web-services, servicepoint

When would you need to adjust these two settings (below)? And what do these two numbers mean for `HttpWebRequest` instances that I make?

1. `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`
2. `System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime`

Are `ServicePoint` objects specific to a domain name or each unique URI requested?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a great explanation:

[Understanding MaxServicePointIdleTime and DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/jpsanders/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit)

Comment: The link is broken :(
But this might be the new URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/jpsanders/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit

Comment: Fixed the link in the post.  Thanks @flayn